# Simple DC failover circuit required

Tags: switches

What I would like, is a circuit diagram that shows me how to constantly monitor a dc voltage of either (say)7.8v DC or 11.8v. If that voltage drops below (for instance) 7.4v or 11.2v under load, a latched LED indicator is shown and the circuit switches (relay?) to a second dc supply. It would be even better if switchover voltage could be set with a variable resistor somewhere in the circuit.

Anybody here who flies radio controlled aircraft will see that this is will provide an emergency flight pack to get you home and indicate that the primary source voltage has dropped.

Edited to make it clearer of what I am trying to ask (thanks for feedback so far).
Ian

Comment: http://www.freelancer.com/

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Hi, sorry my first time on this website so maybe not the right place to ask for a circuit diagram?

Comment: What I am trying to achieve is a sort of failover switch when the voltage on one dc power supply drops below a pre-determined level. This needs to be indicated via a latched LED and also a second dc power supply takes over. I once built a very simple switch over using a darlington pair and a zener but it was pretty crude.

Comment: Hey guys forget it. I have been reading Olins views about bad questions. My subject line actually stated what I wanted in 5 words. I thought I read somewhere that this was 'THE SITE TO COME TO, TO GET ANSWERS'. Sure you have a lot of clever of people on this site but if down voting something you haven't read properly is the way to go I don't need it. Olin you can close this question anytime you want.

Comment: @user28269, it's not really the right place to ask for complete designs. If you give it a go yourself (maybe research comparators, how to switch relays etc) and run into specific problems that would be the basis of a much better question. Even if your proposed design has a dozen problems it will come across much better if you've shown an attempt to research and solve it yourself.

Comment: Whining about how you are being treated is never a way to get better treatment.  You get good treatment by asking a good question and cooperating when people point out shortcomings and ask for more information.  Arrogant and blatantly wrong attitudes like thinking your 5 word subject line is a complete spec and that assuming all downvotes are because the question wasn't read properly makes it even worse.  If you really can't see why a question with that little information can't be answered, then you're right, this site isn't for you.  The volunteers here have other things they can be doing.

Comment: Thank you for your honest feedback. Because the circuit I need is from a requirement I have I don't know for sure if something that does that already exists and I also don't know what that would be called if it is not a fail over. I have made a circuit (crude but effective) that works with loss of voltage but I need one that switches at a pre-selected voltage. I am getting there and will put up the circuit for ideas to improve it once I get it nearer to what I want it to do.

Answer (score 1):

Ian, Before I give you something of an answer, let me tell you possibly why you got downvoted (and also why it is hard for us to give you an answer).  I didn't give you a DV, so I can't say exactly why, but I can guess.  And the reasons are this:  You didn't tell us enough of what you are trying to do, then the only "obvious" question is if you need a relay or not.  To make matters worse, you presume to already know the solution to the real problem (DC failover)  and you get mad at us when we ask questions.  As you question is currently formed, there is little hope that any of us can give you a proper solution to your real problem. But I will try anyway, so bear with me here.

Your Q mentioned switching, and the voltages of the two supplies, but it didn't mention anything about the current that the two supplies will be doing.  I don't do RC-anything so I am not familiar with it.  I also don't know if you are powering the radio (low current) or an electric motor (very high current).  I will assume an electric motor at maybe 10 amps RMS.

Without knowing more about your application, I suspect that you don't really want a failover battery supply.  More on that in a minute, but first let me address some of the points in your Q.

A relay isn't what you want to use. They are heavy, waste power, and are sensitive to vibrations.  What you probably want is a couple of MOSFET's to do the switching, along with some schottky diodes.  The MOSFETs do the switching, and the diodes make sure that you are not backfeeding power into the "unused" battery from the selected battery.  You can use a voltage comparator or opamp to compare the power to a threshold voltage and decide how to switch.  You'll need a reference voltage, made from a precision voltage reference IC, a linear regulator, or a resistor+zener+cap.  The simplest MOSFET to use would be a P-Channel type, but they will have poor on-resistance and will waste power.  An N-Channel MOSFET would be more ideal, but will be difficult to drive since you'll need about 16v or more to properly turn them on.

I mention MOSFET stuff rather quickly and without much explanation because I don't actually think that this is what you want to do.

In an electric RC plane, I don't think that switching to a backup battery is all that useful.  What you really want to know is when there is just enough power left in your battery to turn around and land.  Instead of having two batteries, have one larger one, or two identical ones in parallel.  Then monitor their charge level and light the LED when the charge level drops to some threshold.

This would better utilize the power in the batteries (giving you a longer flying time), and less power wasted in the switching circuit.

The problem with this is that monitoring the charge level of modern batteries (I assume some form of lithium) is difficult.  You could just watch the output voltage, but that is an inaccurate method.  Modern laptop circuits watch both the charge voltage/current and the discharge current/voltage to figure it out.  There are chips out there specifically for this application.

If this alternative approach to your problem seems reasonable, then you'd need to do some research on your own (probably reading app notes on these charge monitoring chips) and then come back here when you have a specific question about some aspect of this solution.

Comment: To add to what David said, those charge monitoring chips are sometimes called battery *fuel gauge* chips.  That might be useful search term.

Comment: Good point, @OlinLathrop!

Comment: David and Olin, thank you. Yes I think I need to look more at voltage comparator and use of MOSFET for switching (2amp - 4amp). The problem with Lipo batteries is that they can suddenly fade very quickly. On board voltage indicators are almost useless because you can't see them when they are most needed.